# Group lines of a function in vim

Tags: vim, syntax

Is there an feature in vim to group lines on the same nesting level like in an IDE, using some kind of vertical lines (i.e. pipes)?

I think of something like this:

```
def myfunct():
|    print "hello world
|    for i in range(5):
||        print i
|    print "goodbye"
```

where | are unprintable syntax highlighting chars.

Comment: See `:help folding`.

Comment: I do not want any folding, just some visual indicator, where a block starts and ends.

Comment: With folding you can have a fold column that shows approximately what you're looking for.

Comment: I will look into it. I just hate anything, which automatically or accidentally folds code, but like some stuff showing the structure of the code.

Comment: There are a few of these. I have never found one I really liked, they are cluttered IMO. But here: (1) [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides), (2) [Indent Guides](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3361), (3) [IndentLine.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4354)